# wslでgit cloneをしようとするとタイムアウトになる。

Tags: wsl

**環境**
windows10 home
git version 2.25.1
wsl2

**〇やりたいこと**
git cloneでリポジトリをクローンしたいと考えています。

**問題点**
例えば以下のコードを入力すると次のようになります。

```
git clone https://github.com/anyenv/anyenv ~/.anyenv
```

こちらを実行した結果、

```
Cloning into '/home/username/.anyenv'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/anyenv/anyenv/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

となってしまいます。

コマンドプロンプトに入力した結果は無事実行されたのでおそらくwsl上の設定がおかしいのかなと思うのですが、原因は何でしょうか？

そもそもgitに限らず、
curl https://google.com　などを打ち込んでもtimeoutになってしまうのですが、どうすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: この辺の記事関連かもしれませんね。[GitでProxyの設定を行ってエラー回避する方法](https://git-manual.net/git-proxy-error/), [WSL2上のUbuntuで最初にする作業まとめ](https://qiita.com/nab/items/18b5b6092ae0fc31a457), [WSL2の環境構築メモ（プロキシ設定とか）](https://yksnyh-lab.cyou/wsl2-develop-env/)

Comment: 直接の原因まではわかりませんが、そもそも WSL 内の環境から外部ネットワークにつながっていないのだと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おそらく、仮想環境であるWSLからPCを経由して外側のポートにアクセスできない、という状況かと思います。
Docker等でも同様の問題が起きると思います。

この辺りの記事が役立ちそうです。

[Windows WSL2に外部から直接アクセスするための設定](https://rcmdnk.com/blog/2021/03/01/computer-windows-network/)

あとは`Win＋S`でPC自体のファイアウォールを確認してみてください。

Comment: 私の場合、以下のURLを参考にした結果無事解決しました！https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/networking

Comment: 無事解決して良かったです。また、解決したリンクをご提示くださりありがとうございます。